# InputTextArea primesface html content and width issues

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am going to write the page with textarea control in which user will input the text with some formatting similar to html, e.g. link or color or fonts. Then in another page user can see the text in formatting.
Which controls and function that I can use in input formatting and output to text?

Comment: Moreover, how can I adjust the width of the textarea control??

Comment: Look at the PrimeFaces documentation

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputTextarea.xhtml)

```
<p:inputTextarea rows="10" cols="50" ... />
```

Comment: use outputText to show output with escape='false' in outputText tag. It is working. Thanks,